# trying to add a basic like button to my website but the code is not working

Tags: facebook-like

I am trying to add a basic like button to my website but the code is not working i am getting the following error: Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in. I am copying and pasting the url of my Facebook Home page is this incorrect?

This is the code I am entering in the Facebook Page URL box.

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Cheap-CD-Duplications-Inc/135138926577670?sk=app_158086484245654

Answer (score 1):

David your link is to a tab application on your page.  You need to remove the sk=app_158....... from the url.

the url you need to use is...
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Cheap-CD-Duplications-Inc/135138926577670

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
2. Paste your URL into "URL to Like" field and press "Get Code" button.
3. Copy the code and paste it on your web site, wherever you want to display it.